# How to change the existing html text in a D3 rect?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to change the existing html text in a D3 rect to something else on the click of a button. There is an image on the top right corner of a D3 rect. When I click on that image the text inside the rect has to change to another html text like This is new text . It would be great if anyone could help me figure out a way to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <script
      data-require="d3@3.5.3"
      data-semver="3.5.3"
      src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"
    ></script> -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
          y = text.attr('y'),
          x = text.attr('x')
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
          tspan = text
          .text(null)
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', x)
          .attr('y', y)
          .attr('dy', dy + 'em');
        while ((word = words.pop())) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(' '));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(' '));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text
              .append('tspan')
              .attr('x', x)
              .attr('y', y)
              .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
              .text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    var svg = d3
      .select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 5000);

    // var longText =
    //   'This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text. This is very very long text.';

    var longText =
      '<span>This is very very long textThis is very very long textThis is very very long textThis is very very long text</span>';

    var totHeight = 0;

    drawRect();

    function drawRect() {
      //var someWidth = randomIntFromInterval(40, 300);
      var someWidth = 212;

      var g = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(20,' + totHeight + ')');

      var rect = g
        .append('rect')
        .style('fill', 'steelblue')
        .attr('x', 50)
        .attr('y', 50)
        .attr('width', someWidth)
        .attr('height', 1);

      var txt = g
        .append('text')
        .html(longText)
        .attr('x', 70)
        .attr('y', 70)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('fill', 'black')
        .call(wrap, someWidth - 28);

      var img = g.append('svg:image')
        .attr('x', 250)
        .attr('y', 40)
        .attr('width', 24)
        .attr('height', 24)
        .attr(
          'xlink:href',
          './img/edit-24-px.svg'
        );

        img.on('click', function () {
        //d3.append('text').html("<span> bye </span>");
        console.log('hi');
        
        });  

      var height = txt.node().getBBox().height + 25;
      totHeight += height + 10;
      rect.attr('height', height);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/passionateCoder/prh2acot/

I am not able to add an image to the JSFiddle.

Comment: Use the tag <text> in an SVG to add text.  Then you can add copy to the text tag using the d3's .text method.

Comment: I used the g.append('text') to append the text. Could you give me a code sample on how I can change this text on click on the image. `img.on('click', function () {});`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
img.on('click', function () {
        txt.text('this is new text')   
        });
```

Or for innerHTML:

```
img.on('click', function () {
        txt.html('this is new text')   
        });
```

Remember that you cannot use traditional HTML in SVG Texts. Read here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

Comment: Thank you for the above code snippet. The above is working fine. The only problem I am facing is when I try `txt.html('<span>this is new text</span>')` it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to wrap?

Comment: So the text is not just pure text. It has html embedded in it too. There is a warp function in that code which seems to be working fine.

Comment: Right. You can't do that with SVG Text. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need the spans added to it? Text does allow for the use of Tspan. Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan
Would that do the trick?

Comment: It would be great if you can take a look at the code snippet I provided and suggest what modifications I need to do to the code to make it work. That would be really helpful as I am new to these SVG and D3 concepts.